# How to format entire row when any cell of the row contains any value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I want when there is any value (whether any alphabetic or numeric value) in any of the cell into the row from a1 to p1 then the entire row (from a1 to p1) should be formatted.

For example there is text say "ok" into d1 then the entire row from a1 to p1 should be formatted with red colour.

Similarly if there is numeric value "78" in m2 then the entire row from a2 to p2 should be formatted with red colour and so on.

And such kind of setting should be applied from a1 to p1000. For better understanding I am attaching a snapshot of excel sheet-

[image: http://i.imgur.com/hGo5aaL.png]

Comment: We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: 'Conditional formatting' does that, read its help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like all you need is to apply conditional formatting to your data range. Take a look at Excel help on how to use this feature. Use =COUNTA()>0 as the conditional formatting formula and select the range of columns in one row, no $ signs around the cell ranges. Be aware that the conditional formatting interface is tricky. When editing your formula in the interface, use the F2 key and watch the bottom left of the application window to make sure your cursor is in Edit mode rather than in the Point or Enter modes. When you're ready to put your fist through the screen then you're probably getting close to having it right.